# Generating a configuration model networkx graph from an original graph, but the two have different number of edges

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have a graph `G` with the following properties

```
{'node_num': 63717,
 'edges_num': 373718}
```

and I am trying to generate a configuration model graph as follows with networkx:

```
cm = nx.configuration_model([y[1] for y in G.degree()], nx.Graph(),seed = 42)
```

So I feed to the model all the degree sequences of the original nodes from the graph `G`. I end up getting a cm graph with these properties:

```
{'node_num': 63717,
 'edges_num': 373602
}
```

But shouldn't the two edges number match because I am generating cm from the same exact degrees?

If so, it could be a problem related to the original graph `G` I am considering?

Answer (score 1):

Since `nx.configuration_model` generates a random graph, that can contain self-edges and duplicate edges, its final count of nodes and edges may differ from the nodes/edges of the reference graph.

If you are looking to rewire the original graph while maintaining the node/edge characteristics, it might be better to start with a copy of the graph and make manual adjustments to the edges.